# How to solve $e^{ix} = i$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am taking an on-line course and the following homework problem was posed: $$e^{ix} = i$$ I have no idea how to solve this problem. I have never dealt with solving equations that have imaginary parts. What are the steps to solving such equations? I am familiar with Taylor series and the Euler formula if that is any help.

Thanks.

Comment: the important thing to notice here is that there is more than one $x$ which works.

Comment: Just curious: what online course?  If it's free, there might be others (such as myself) who may be interested... `:)`

Comment: @anorton It is called "Calculus: Single Variable" and it can be found on coursera.org

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So, you say that you're okay with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x),$$ and it should be clear that (for real numbers $a,b,c,d$), we have $$a+bi=c+di\quad\iff\quad a=c\;\text{ and }\;b=d.$$
So, which values of $x$ will satisfy
$$\cos(x)+\sin(x)i=0+1i\quad ?$$

Comment: To tack onto this answer.. there will be _many_ such values of $x$ that solve the above equality.

Comment: @ZevChonoles how do you know that $\cos(x)+\sin(x)i=0+1i\quad$ Where did you find $0+1i$? Why are we assuming that $\cos(x)$ is zero and $\sin(x)$ is one?

Comment: @gekkostate:  that is the point of the two equivalent equations.  We know $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are real for real $x$ so you can identify real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @RossMillikan But how do you know that it is equal to $0 + 1i$?

Comment: @gekkostate: I am just restating the problem; it is not something I somehow "know". You're given the equation
$$e^{ix}=i$$
and told to find the values of $x$ for which this is true. But
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$
and
$$i=0+1i$$
so you are, equivalently, finding the values of $x$ for which
$$\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=0+1i.$$

Comment: @ZevChonoles Sorry, so by definition then $i = 0+1i$ or only in this scenario?

Comment: @gekkostate: For any complex number $a$ whatsoever, we have $1\cdot a=a$ and $0+a=a$, so
$$0+(1\cdot a)=0+a=a.$$

Comment: @gekkostate if I have no reals and one $i$, then I just have $i$. $0+1i=i$.

Answer (score 9):

$$e^{ix} = i$$
[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x),$$
so:
$$\cos x+i\sin x = 0+1\cdot i$$
compare real and imaginary parts
$$\sin x =1$$ and $$\cos x =0$$
$$x=\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}\;\;,n \in \mathbb W$$
(W stands for set of whole number $W=${$0,1,2,3,.......,n$}).

Comment: @iostream007 Can you please explain the first two lines? How does $e^{ix} = i$ translate to $\cos x+i\sin x = 0+1\cdot i$?

Comment: @gekkostate [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula):

Comment: $e^{ix}=\cos x+\sin x$ comes from euler's formula and $i$ has written as $0+1\cdot i$

Answer (score 4):

Well, the *geometric meaning* of $e^{ix}$ is the weapon here to use.

This is nothing but the point on the complex plane which has length $1$ and angle $x$ measured from the right half of the real axis, in radian. So that $e^{i\pi}=-1$, for example.

Comment: -1: This is the best representation, but from my experience a student using this method will only give one answer.

Comment: But the student will *see*, that's more important for long term.. :)

Answer (score 3):

A completely different approach:

$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 \implies \sqrt {e^{i\pi}} = \sqrt {-1} \implies e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}} = i $$

Comment: Can you explain why you chose the 'positive' value of the square root?

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to think in terms of radial co-ordinates rather than cartesian.  Whenever you see a complex exponential it's best to think of the geometric interpretation first, if possible.

The radial representation of a complex number $z = a + bi$ is $Re^{i\theta}$
where $R = |z|$ and $\theta=arctan(b/a)$.

So for the number i we ask ourselves what is R, and what is $\theta?$
We look where the point i is on the complex plane - it's on the y axis 1 unit away from the origin. So R is 1 and $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  (Note that you can add any multiple of $2\pi$ to $\theta$ and things stay the same.)

So plug these R, $\theta$ values into the radial form of z to get the radial representation for i which is  $1.e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$
So $e^{ix} = i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and a naive answer is $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
But remember we could add any multiple of $2{\pi}$ to our angle for i so we need to add $2n{\pi}$ for the general answer.

Hence $x = \frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Best answer by far

Answer (score 2):

$$ e^{ix} = i \implies ix =\ln(i) \implies ix= \ln(|i|)-i \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right) $$

$$ \implies x = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\quad k\in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$e^{xi}=i=e^{\frac\pi2i+2k\pi i}\implies x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$